# std::ranges::elements_view for custom tuple-like data

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts, stdtuple, range-v3

I have an use case that can be reduced to:

```
#include <vector>
#include <ranges>
#include <tuple>

struct TDat
{
  double x, y;

  template <std::size_t I>
  friend double &get(TDat &Dat)
    { if constexpr (I == 0) return Dat.x; else return Dat.y; }

  template <std::size_t I>
  friend double const &get(TDat const &Dat)
    { if constexpr (I == 0) return Dat.x; else return Dat.y; }
};

namespace std
{

template <>
struct tuple_size<TDat> : integral_constant<size_t, 2u> {};

template <size_t I>
struct tuple_element<I, TDat>
  { using type = double; };

} // std

class TTable
{
private:
  std::vector<TDat> DatVec;

public:  
  auto GetxVec()
    { return std::views::keys(DatVec); }
};
```

That piece of code does not compile with G++ 10 because `TDat` does not model `__has_tuple_element<std::ranges::range_value_t<_Vp>, _Nm>`. The problem seems to be that this concept is defined as (https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/fab263ab0fc10ea08409b80afa7e8569438b8d28/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/ranges#L3318):

```
  namespace __detail
  {
    template<typename _Tp, size_t _Nm>
    concept __has_tuple_element = requires(_Tp __t)
      {
    typename tuple_size<_Tp>::type;
    requires _Nm < tuple_size_v<_Tp>;
    typename tuple_element_t<_Nm, _Tp>;
    { std::get<_Nm>(__t) }
      -> convertible_to<const tuple_element_t<_Nm, _Tp>&>;
      };
  }
```

I believe that, since the call to `get` is qualified, the compiler cannot find my `get` functions. Is that conclusion correct? If so, is that the intended behaviour? Is it defined behaviour to define my get functions in the `std` namespace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I believe that, since the call to get is qualified, the compiler cannot find my `get` functions. Is that conclusion correct?

Yes.

> If so, is that the intended behaviour?

That's the *specified* behavior at least. [[range.elements.view]](http://eel.is/c++draft/range.elements.view) defines the concept as:

```
  template<class T, size_t N>
  concept has-tuple-element =                   // exposition only
    requires(T t) {
      typename tuple_size<T>::type;
      requires N < tuple_size_v<T>;
      typename tuple_element_t<N, T>;
      { get<N>(t) } -> convertible_to<const tuple_element_t<N, T>&>;
    };
```

where all functions calls in the standard library are implicitly fully qualified unless described otherwise [[library.contents]/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/library#contents-3):

> Whenever a name `x` defined in the standard library is mentioned, the name `x` is assumed to be fully qualified as `​::​std​::​x`, unless explicitly described otherwise.

There is no description otherwise here.

However, whether it's intended or not is a different question. And the answer there is also yes. The Library doesn't actually have a "TupleLike" concept yes. Yes, structured bindings exist, but there's no formal specification of that in the Library yet - so until that happens, all the tuple-like algorithms only work for standard library tuple-like things (`pair`, `array`, `tuple`, etc.)

> Is it defined behaviour to define my get functions in the std namespace?

No, you may not.

Comment: So, there's no workaround, right? In other words, does `elements_view` only work with *standard* tuple-like classes?

Comment: @metalfox Yes, that's correct. We don't really have a real "tuple-like" protocol yet.